# Is it possible to keep method independent of template arguments in separate compilation unit?

Tags: c++

Today I got the idea that if I have template class with no attributes connected to template arguments an a method that doesn't touch any template arguments also, it should be possible to compile this method separately.
Unfortunately the ARM compiler doesn't allow me to do this.

Is it legal according to standard? Is there any special grammatical construction for this?

Comment: Got an example in the form of code? I can't really tell what you want.

Comment: Just make a normal function and have the all instances of the template method call the function.

Comment: If you have significant parts (data / function members) of a class template that do not depend on the template arguments, then those parts should be factored out has normal classes and functions (that can be implemented separately) that can be used by the class template.